# Как убрать номер порта :8000 из доменного имени nginx, uwsgi?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, wsgi

Работаю по одному из множеств очень похожих туториалов на тему деплой на боевом сервере с использованием nginx, uwsgi - https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html. Все делал по туториалу. На каждом этапе проходил предлагаемые проверки. Настроил файл my_site_nginx.conf в корневой папке проекта:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/momstyle.sock;
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name momstyle-kzn.ru;

    location /static/  {
        alias /home/django/momstyle/static/;
    }

    location /media/  {
        alias /home/django/momstyle/media/;
    }

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass django;
    }
    access_log /home/django/momstyle-access.log;
    error_log /home/django/momstyle-error.log;

}
```

создал для файла ссылку в директории etc/nginx/sites-enabled/, открыл доступ пользователю www-data  ко всем нужным файлам

File: momstyle_uwsgi.ini

```
# mysite_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /home/django/momstyle
# Django's wsgi file
module          = momstyle.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /home/django/venv

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /tmp/momstyle.sock
chmod-socket    = 664
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
plugins = python
```

При запуске команды

```
 uwsgi --socket /tmp/momstyle.sock --ini momstyle_uwsgi.ini
```

все работает отлично, но по адресу domain_name.ru:8000(momstyle-kzn.ru:8000, в моем случае). На данном этапе в туториале сайт уже запускается по адресу domain_name.ru без номера порта. Собственно вопрос, как убрать номер порта и находить свой сайт по нормальному адресу?

Comment: В разделе server вы слушаете порт 8000. Попробуйте слушать 80.

Comment: Благодарю! Все сработало как нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Решение

```
 server {
 listen 80;
 }
```

в файле my_project_nginx.conf

```
service nginx restart
```